# Getting Failed to access Environment Variables in Windows using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to access an account Id that I have stored in my local system.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\shiva>echo %TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID%
Cfc0db83ecf359067cb7289850db
```

I am able to view the value stored in the variable in CMD but when trying to access the same value in Spring code I am getting null

Here are some ways I have tried to access the variables

```
  1. public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");

  2.  @Value("${TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}")
        private  String accountSID;
  3. @Autowired
     private Environment env;
     System.out.println(env.getProperty("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get all the values from my environment variable using the same :-

[image]

Can you paste your logs and show what is the exact error are you facing ?